# Swell Spectral Transform

Tags: fourier-transform, oceanography

For understanding the quality of surf in general, I find that directional spectral plots, like [this](http://cdip.ucsd.edu/?nav=recent&sub=observed&pub=public&map_stati=1,2,3&stn=100&stream=p1&units=english&tz=PST&xitem=dir_spectrum) also below, are the best way for me to get a quick mental picture. I want to make a kind of video of these images so I can visually see surf evolution. CDIP offers XYZ displacement data, like [this](http://cdip.ucsd.edu/?nav=recent&sub=observed&pub=public&map_stati=1,2,3&stn=100&stream=p1&units=english&tz=PST&xitem=xplot), but I don't know exactly what the transform is to go from XYZ displacement to a directional spectrum.

My naive intuition would be that the functions spanning the space might look something like,

\begin{align}
\vec{\psi}(t; \omega, \theta) &= \hat{x} \sin \omega t \sin \theta + \hat{y} \sin \omega t \cos \theta + \hat{z} \cos \omega t
\end{align}

I imagine that this might work because I have read that swell move in circles vertically and in the direction the swell is propagating. Thus the displacement on the X-Y plane will be handled by the $ \sin \theta, \cos \theta $ terms while the time cyclic terms handle the swell movement.

I would then decompose (numerically) the waves by doing the integral,

$$
F(\omega, \theta) = N^{-1} \int_\mathbb{R} dt\ \ \vec{f}(t) \cdot \vec{\psi}(t; \omega, \theta)
$$
where $ N $ is the normalization I would need to work out.

Is this the right way to do the directional spectral decomposition?

[image: Directional Spectrum]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called "Directional Spectrum of Ocean/Sea Waves".

**Theory**

The credit for this method goes to Longuet-Higgens. His paper is miserable to find, but I linked a scan of it below.

Using some relations from deep water Airy Wave Theory, we get the particle displacement field elements,

\begin{align}
\xi_i(\vec{x}, t) &= \mathbb{Re}\left[ \int d^2k\ p_i A(k)\ e^{i(k\cdot x - \omega t)} \right] \\
p_i &= (i \cos \phi, i \sin \phi, 1)_i
\end{align}
with $ \phi $ being the angle of the momentum vector $ k $.

The energy density is,
\begin{align}
E(k)d^2k &= \frac{1}{2}A(k)\overline{A(k)} d^2k \\
E(\omega, \phi) d\omega d\phi &= \frac{1}{2}A(\omega, \phi)\overline{A(\omega, \phi)} \frac{d^2k}{d\omega d\phi} d\omega d\phi \\
  &= \frac{1}{2}A(\omega, \phi)\overline{A(\omega, \phi)} \frac{k dk}{d\omega} d\omega d\phi \\
E(\omega, \phi) &= \frac{1}{2}A(\omega, \phi)\overline{A(\omega, \phi)} \frac{k dk}{d\omega}
\end{align}

Lets define,
\begin{align}
C_{ij} &= \frac{1}{2} \int_{[0, 2\pi]} d\phi \frac{d^2k}{d\omega d\phi} (p_i A(k)) \overline{(p_j A(k))} \\
  &= \int_{[0, 2\pi]} d\phi\ p_i \overline{p_j} E(\omega, \phi)
\end{align}

Note the symmetric tensor,
\begin{align}
p_i \overline{p_j} &= 
\begin{bmatrix}
\cos^2 \phi & \cos \phi \sin \phi & \cos \phi \\
\cdot & \sin^2 \phi & \sin \phi \\
\cdot & \cdot & 1
\end{bmatrix} \\
  &= 
\begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{4} \left(e^{i2\phi} + e^{-i2\phi} + 2 \right) & \frac{1}{4i} \left(e^{i2\phi} - e^{-i2\phi} \right) & \frac{1}{2}\left(e^{i\phi} + e^{-i\phi}\right) \\
\cdot & \frac{1}{4} \left(2 - e^{i2\phi} - e^{-i2\phi} \right) & \frac{1}{2i}\left(e^{i\phi} - e^{-i\phi}\right) \\
\cdot & \cdot & 1
\end{bmatrix} \\
\end{align}

We note that the Fourier series on $ \phi $ is,
\begin{align}
E(\omega, \phi) &= \sum_n E_n e^{in\phi} \\
E_n &= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{[0, 2\pi]} E(\omega, \phi) e^{-in\phi} \\
\end{align}

Mixing and matching the $ C_{ij} $ we get,
\begin{align}
E_0 &= \frac{1}{2\pi} C_{00} \\
E_1 &= \overline{E_{-1}} = \frac{1}{2\pi} (C_{13} - iC_{23}) \\
E_2 &= \overline{E_{-2}} = 2(C_{11} - C_{22}) + 4i C_{12}
\end{align}

**Part I can't figure out!!**

In order to get the $ C_{ij} $, I would expect to evaluate the integral at $ x=0 $ because I only have one data source so I can't integrate over space,

\begin{align}
\int dt \xi_i(x=0) \overline{\xi}_j(x=0) &= \int d^2k\ d^2k'\ p_i \overline{p_j} A(k) \overline{A(k')} \delta(\omega - \omega') \\
  &= \int d\omega d\omega' d\phi d\phi' \left[k(\omega) \frac{dk}{d\omega} \right] \left[k(\omega') \frac{dk'}{d\omega'} \right] p_i(\phi) \overline{p_j(\phi')} A(\omega, \phi) \overline{A(\omega', \phi')} \delta(\omega - \omega') \\
  &= \int d\omega d\phi d\phi' \left[k(\omega) \frac{dk}{d\omega} \right]^2 p_i(\phi) \overline{p_j(\phi')} A(\omega, \phi) \overline{A(\omega, \phi')} \\
\end{align}

I may be off by an overall normalization, but I can't move the integral past this to get anything that looks like $ C_{ij} $ because of that integral over $ \phi' $. I don't have a delta function for $ \phi' $ and thus I get a kind of averaging over $ \phi' $ which is inappropriate for my goals.

**Conclusion**

Donelan et al. states that you need many points to collect data.

**Sources:**

[Donelan MA, Hamilton J, Hui WH. Directional spectra of wind
generated waves. Phil Trans R Soc London 1985;A315:509–62.](http://rsta.royalsocietypublishing.org/content/315/1534/509)

[Observaton of the Directional Spectrum of Sea Waves Using the Motion of a Floating Bouy by Longuet-Higgens](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4VM0JucnD9QaHdUeFJtSnZVSlE/view?usp=sharing)

[Wikipedia Airy Wave Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_wave_theory#Table_of_wave_quantities)

[NOAA](http://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/wavemeas.pdf)

[Section 2.1 of this](http://projects.knmi.nl/geoss/cost/Cost_Action_714_deel_1.pdf)